# Spring boot TaskExector makes API execution slower

Tags: spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor

I'm making use of `TaskExecutor` to run some tasks in background threads. Following is my configuration:-

```
@Configuration
public class TaskExecutorConfig
{

@Bean
public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor()
{

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("TaskExecutor");
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();

    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}
```

}

There can be many tasks to run in background. I have declared a `ThreadComponent` implementing `Runnable` class. In this `ThreadComponent`, I have declared methods which get executed based on condition. Following is the component and what it somewhat looks like:-

```
public class ThreadComponent implements Runnable
{

....
....
....
....

public ThreadComponent()
{

    //................//
    //Initialization code for variables and some autowired components//
    //................//
}

@Override
public void run()
{

    if (condition)
        doThis();
    else if (condition)
        doThat();
    else if (condition)
        doThen();
    else if (condition)
        doWhere();
    else if (condition)
        doHow();
    else if (condition)
        doWhen();
    else if (condition)
        doNothing();
}

public void doThis() {
......
.....,
}

public void doThat() {
......
.....,
}

public void doThen() {
......
.....,
}

public void doWhere() {
......
.....,
}

public void doHow() {
......
.....,
}

public void doWhen() {
......
.....,
}

public void doNothing() {
......
.....,
}

}
```

I call this component using `TaskExecutor` for tasks. In `ThreadComponent`, I have also used `@Autowired` components which I initialize in the constructor using `ApplicationContext`. But this is making my processing slow. I need help so how can I optimize my code to make it better.

**Update**

Please find the class variables and constructor of the component:

```
private DTO dto1;
private DTO2 dto2;
private Map<String, Object> dtoVal;
private String schemaName;
private int checkCondition;
private AppUser user;
private Details oldApprovalDetails;
private Details newApprovalDetails;
private ThreadDTO threadDTO;

@Autowired
OcrService ocrService;

@Autowired
NotificationService notificationService;

@Autowired
CreateRecordsService createRecordService;

@Autowired
DtoService dtoService;

@Autowired
DtoCalculations dtoCalculations;

@Autowired
MailService mailService;

@Autowired
TransDtoRepository transDtoRepository;

@Autowired
TransDtoApproverDetailsRepository approverDetails;


public ThreadComponent(ThreadDTO threadDTO,
        List<Details> approvalDetails, ApplicationContext ctx)
{


    this.dto1 = threadDTO.getDto1();
    this.dto2 = threadDTO.getDto2();
    this.dtoVal = threadDTO.getDto1().getConfig();
    this.schemaName = threadDTO.getDto1().getSchemaName();
    this.checkCondition = threadDTO.getCheckCondition();
    this.user = threadDTO.getUser();
    this.oldApprovalDetails = approvalDetails.get(0);
    this.newApprovalDetails = approvalDetails.get(1);
    this.threadDTO = threadDTO;
    this.ocrService = ctx.getBean(OcrService.class);
    this.notificationService = ctx.getBean(NotificationService.class);
    this.createRecordService = ctx.getBean(CreateRecordsService.class);
    this.dtoService = ctx.getBean(DtoService.class);
    this.dtoCalculations = ctx.getBean(DtoCalculations.class);
    this.mailService = ctx.getBean(MailService.class);
    this.transDtoRepository = ctx.getBean(TransDtoRepository.class);
    this.approverDetails = ctx.getBean(TransDtoApproverDetailsRepository.class);

}
```

Constructor contains all the variables declared in class scope.

Comment: Please show your full component (at least the constructor). Also the `maxPoolSize` doesn't have any effect without setting a queue size.

Comment: The autowiring doesn't make sense as you wire everything in the constructor. Also the fact that you use threading doesn't mean it will be faster, only it will execute async. And as stated only 4 will be executed at a time as the max threads doesn't help without a reasonable queue size (default is unbounded so unprocessed task will get into the queue until 1 of the 4 threads is free to start processing.

Comment: Actually, the tasks I have added in my component are really time consuming and have reference to external APIs. So, if these tasks run in background and the app provides response to front end without wasting time then that will be beneficial. And the point is, it is still taking the same amount of time as it was taking earlier. I just need a proper way to implement this so that the background process do not interrupt the response to front end. I tried setting queue capacity as 100, still not useful.

Comment: If you wait for the result then running them in the background won't help. How are you passing things to run async?

Comment: Also how is your instance being constructed? Probably in a controller then. Please add that to your question as well.

Comment: I'm not waiting for the result from these background running tasks. They are only meant for notification and mail purpose or saving data in background. I know this for sure that the data is going to be saved and so I do not mean to check the result. Also, I call these background processes through service and I have autowired TaskExecutor in my service. I call TaskExecutor like this - `taskExecutor.execute(new ThreadComponent(threadDTO, approvalDetails,
                AppContext.getApplicationContext()))`

Comment: That static accessor is a bit concerning. Actually your whole `ThreadComponent` is with all the if/else constructs in there.

Comment: What I don't get what do you mean by slow? There are 4 threads processing your tasks, each task will still take the same amount of time as it did before but execution will probably be delayed.

Comment: Without TaskExecutor the processing used to take around 6 - 8 seconds. After implementing TaskExecutor sometimes it takes 5 seconds, sometimes 10, sometimes 20 and sometimes 35 - 40 seconds. Time taken is not uniform. What I mean is if these threads are executing in background then it shouldn't affect foreground processing.

Comment: Well that actually depends on how many threads are active... If you have too many threads it can (and will) impact the overall performance of your application and might even degrade performance. Effectivly there are as many threads active as you have (virtual) cores (minus 1 for the monitoring). So yes if you start a lot of threads that might suddently degrade performance. Also as stated you have 4 threads, and depending on how many tasks there are it is put in a queue. If there are 20 in the queue yours might be 21 an until it is its turn it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a work around and that helped me solve my issue. I implemented spring boot `@Async` annotation service and added all my backend code that doesn't require to interrupt the user in that service. This service then makes call to the `TaskExecutor` for multiple threads. In short, I implemented both `@Async` and `TaskExecutor` framework for one complex functionality and that made my code faster (now it takes **300 milliseconds** to **500 milliseconds** to give me response).

Hope this helps anyone who is in need.